I'm having problems trying to use pytesseract in visual studio code
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'<C:\Users\dlhst\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract>'
(I tried this line with tesseract.exe at the end and it still gave me the exact same results)
These are the lines I used to initialize tesseract and opencv, because I am trying to make my code capture images from my webcam. However I always get the following error message in the terminal:
enter image description here
It gives me this error even though I have added the path to tesseract in my computer's path:
enter image description here
If anyone has enctountered this problem and has solutions please let me know this would be greatly appreciated!
As said before, the plan is to use opencv and tesseract to capture image from my webcam to detect circled text and add it to a python list. I have not been able to test it yet though because of the path problem in vs code.

just include the path of your tesseract-ocr into the env variables. don't include app data ones. for more detail go here.

I did, yet it still does not work. Showing the same error even by putting it env variables without app data

okay so follow the below steps that I did to make it work:


install it from source forge


make a dev named folder in C Drive and extract the tesseract-ocr there.


Then copy the path that will somewhat look like C:\dev\tesseract-OCR and paste it into your path.


close your existing terminal and open it again and then run your code.


There is a high chance that after adding it in the path you are running it on the same terminal.
